# How to create a 2D area with repeated element from two separate 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arraylist

I am new to Python and I will appreciate any help.

I have 2 different 1D array as follows:

```
Lon_gp = np.arange(10,20,0.25 ).reshape(-1,1)
Lat_gp = np.arange(40,50,0.25 ).reshape(-1,1)
```

I will like to convert the 2 Arrays into a single 2D array as follows

| Lon_list | Lat_list |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 40 |
| 10 | 40.25 |
| 10 | 40.5 |
| 10 | 40.75 |
| ... | ... |
| 10 | 49.25 |
| 10.25 | 40 |
| 10.25 | 40.25 |
| 10.25 | 40.50 |
| 10.25 | 40.75 |

Thank you for your help.

So far, I have just written few line of code

```
n_lon = len(Lon_gp)
n_lat = len(Lat_gp)

lon_list = np.empty(n_lon * n_lat)

for i in Lon_gp:
    a = np.repeat(i, n_lat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) + [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and reshape the result.

```
import numpy as np

Lon_gp = np.arange(10,20,0.25 ).reshape(-1,1)
Lat_gp = np.arange(40,50,0.25 ).reshape(-1,1)

out = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(Lon_gp, Lat_gp, indexing="ij")).reshape(-1, 2)
```

out:

```
array([[10.  , 40.  ],
       [10.  , 40.25],
       [10.  , 40.5 ],
       ...,
       [19.75, 49.25],
       [19.75, 49.5 ],
       [19.75, 49.75]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
np.array([(lon[0],lat[0]) for lon, lat in it.product(Lon_gp, Lat_gp)])
```